# How to add a partial class to a edmx and use it as a navigation property to a existing entity?

Tags: entity-framework

I am going to create a model class of my own as a partial class. How to add this partial class as a navigation property to a existing entity. 
Help me on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you created class yourselves or let some code generator to create it from EDMX file. Your hand made class still must have counter part in EDMX (the entity). Navigation properties are defined among entities in EDMX.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain this with an example?

Comment: EDMX works with those constructs in diagrams not with your classes. By default classes are generated from diagram. If you want to use own class it must still have its representation in diagram and you must modify code generation. There is not too much to show on example. That is about using EF and understand what EDMX is.